# Menú 3 niveles JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Estoy tratando de hacer un menú desplegable con 3 niveles o más;

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function () { // Script del Navegador

    $('#abrir').click(function () {
        $(".cmenu").animate({ "left": "+124px" }, "slow");
    },
        function () {
            $(".cmenu").animate({ "left": "0px" }, "slow"),
                $('#abrir').css('display', 'none');
              
        },
        $('#cerrar').click(function () {
            $(".cmenu").animate({ "left": "-127px" }, "slow");

               $("ul.subnavegador").hide();
        }
        )
    );

    $("ul.subnavegador").hide();
    $("a.desplegable").toggle(
        function () {
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnavegador").slideDown('fast');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnavegador").slideUp('fast');
        }
    );
});
```

```css
.cmenu
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: -124px;
}
.menuoculto
{
    height: 82px;
    width: 28px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 5px;
    display:block;  
}
.menuvisible
{
    margin: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 5px;
    display:block;
 
}
.menu
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 127px;
    top: 1px;
    bottom: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: absolute;
    
}

.subnavegador{
    width: 280px;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Menú vertical desplegable con jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="conmenu" class="cmenu">
        <div id="cerrar" class="menuvisible">&slarr;</div>
        <div id="abrir" class="menuoculto">&raquo;</div>


        <div class="menu">
        <ul class="navegador">
            <li><a href="#" title="Opción 1">Opción 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Opción 2">Opción 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="desplegable" title="Opción 3">Opción 3</a>
                <ul class="subnavegador">
                    <li><a href="#" class="desplegable" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-1">Sub-Opción 3-1</a>
                    
                        <ul class="subnavegador">
                            <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-2.1" class="desplegable">Sub-Opción 3-2.1</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-2">Sub-Opción 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-3">Sub-Opción 3-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-4">Sub-Opción 3-4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="desplegable" title="Opción 4">Opción 4</a>
                <ul class="subnavegador">
                    <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-1">Sub-Opci&oacute;n 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-2">Sub-Opción 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-3">Sub-Opción 3-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-4">Sub-Opción 3-4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando hago click para desplegar uno de los apartados, se despliegan todos los subapartados de este, automaticamente.

Aunque luego pueda cerrarlos y abrir individualmente.

¿Como podría evitar este problema?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un snippet funcional? He creado uno pero con tu código no termina de verse el problema.

Comment: @Kiko_L listo, se ve cuando se despliega la opcion3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () { // Script del Navegador

$('#abrir').click(function () {
    $(".cmenu").animate({ "left": "+124px" }, "slow");
},
    function () {
        $(".cmenu").animate({ "left": "0px" }, "slow"),
            $('#abrir').css('display', 'none');

    },
    $('#cerrar').click(function () {
        $(".cmenu").animate({ "left": "-127px" }, "slow");

           $("ul.subnavegador").hide();
    }
    )
);

/*$("a.desplegable").toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnavegador").slideDown('fast');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnavegador").slideUp('fast');
    }
);*/
$('.desplegable').click(function() {
 if ($(this).next('.subnavegador').is(":hidden")) {
   $(this).next('.subnavegador').slideDown('fast');
  }
  else {
  $(this).next('.subnavegador').slideUp('fast');
  }
});
});
```

```css
.cmenu
{
height: 300px;
width: 500px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 40px;
left: -124px;
}
.menuoculto
{
height: 82px;
width: 28px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
left: 150px;
top: 5px;
display:block;  
}
.menuvisible
{
margin: auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
left: -30px;
top: 5px;
display:block;

}
.menu
{
height: 300px;
width: 127px;
top: 1px;
bottom: 40px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

position: absolute;

}

.subnavegador{
width: 280px;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conmenu" class="cmenu">
    <div id="cerrar" class="menuvisible">&slarr;</div>
    <div id="abrir" class="menuoculto">&raquo;</div>


    <div class="menu">
    <ul class="navegador">
        <li><a href="#" title="Opción 1">Opción 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Opción 2">Opción 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="desplegable" title="Opción 3">Opción 3</a>
            <ul class="subnavegador">
                <li><a href="#" class="desplegable" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-1">Sub-Opción 3-1</a>

                    <ul class="subnavegador">
                        <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-2.1" class="desplegable">Sub-Opción 3-2.1</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-2">Sub-Opción 3-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-3">Sub-Opción 3-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-4">Sub-Opción 3-4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="desplegable" title="Opción 4">Opción 4</a>
            <ul class="subnavegador">
                <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-1">Sub-Opci&oacute;n 3-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-2">Sub-Opción 3-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-3">Sub-Opción 3-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Ir a Sub-Opción 3-4">Sub-Opción 3-4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Tenías varios errores, he trabajado sobre tu código para darte una versión de lo que creo que querías que hiciese tu menú.

Lo primero de todo, he borrado de tu **JS** la siguiente línea:

```
$("ul.subnavegador").hide();
```

Aunque es correcta lo veo innecesario, puesto que mediante **CSS** podías tener ocultos todos los elementos con la clase `.subnavegador`, por lo que añadí en tu **CSS** dicha regla:

```
.subnavegador {
    width: 280px;
    display: none;
}
```

Lo otro que hice fue quitar la siguiente función. No tengo muy claro lo que querías conseguir, pero no estaba funcionando, además de que provocaba que los elementos 3 y 4 se mostrasen ocultos en un inicio:

```
$("a.desplegable").toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnavegador").slideDown('fast');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnavegador").slideUp('fast');
    }
);
```

En su lugar programé la siguiente función:

```
$('.desplegable').click(function() {
    if ($(this).next('.subnavegador').is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next('.subnavegador').slideDown('fast');
    }
    else {
        $(this).next('.subnavegador').slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

Lo que hago es asociar un evento `click()` a los elementos con la clase `.desplegable` luego compruebo si el elemento hermano siguiente (asegurándome de que se trata de la clase `.subnavegador`) se encuentra oculto o visible, desplegándolo o replegándolo según el caso.